# DAR CLICK Y AGREGAR ESTILO A LA FILA SELECCIONADA

Tags: reactjs

Buenas tardes me podrían ayudar, estoy utilizando la dependencia `react-data-table-component` en react js.
Lo que se requiere es que al dar clic en cualquiera de las columnas se seleccione toda la fila, así mismo poder cambiar de color de la fila seleccionada. Y estos datos van ir a un formulario.

me podrían ayudar, estaría muy agradecido.

[image: referencia]

Comment: Deberías agregar a tu pregunta lo que ha realizado bien puedes agregar el código de forma simple, subir tu proyecto a un control de versiones como git con github y compartir el link o puedes usar [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) el cual es un  entorno de desarrollo para aplicaciones web, una vez adentro le das a crear nueva plantilla, escoges la opción de React y vas recreando tu proyecto o al menos la parte que te da problemas, puedes agregar dependencias si lo necesitas.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-galileo-r7p34?file=/src/App.js
algo parecido a este ejemplo, pero lo que hace este es agregar a mas, según lo que veo hace una comparación, pero no se requiere eso.